# Create a method to apply filters in a task list

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a homework assignment with one question I am having difficulty with.

I need to create a method titled changeView that applies filters to an array. The buttons and filters are already written, but I need to code the method that applies them and updates the array with the new view. There are 3 separate buttons: all, active, and completed found in the code.

I've tried calling the switch statement in the method, but I don't think I have either the write syntax, or I am not using the correct variables.

The array name is todos

code from the buttons:

```
<div class="filters">
                <button :class="{selected: view === 'all'}" @click="changeView('all')">All</button>
                <button :class="{selected: view === 'active'}" @click="changeView('active')">Active</button>
                <button @click="changeView('completed')" :class="{selected: view === 'completed'}">Completed</button>
            </div>
```

code from the filters:

```
computed: {
            itemsLeft() {
                return this.todos.filter(t => !t.isDone).length;
            },
            activeTodos() {
                return this.todos.filter(t => !t.isDone);
            },
            completedTodos() {
                return this.todos.filter(t => t.isDone);
            },
            filteredTodos() {
                switch (this.view) {
                    case 'active':
                        return this.activeTodos;
                    case 'completed':
                        return this.completedTodos;
                    default:
                        return this.todos;
```

If there's any more sections of code needed, or if anyone needs all the code lines, I can paste it in. I tried to emit what wasn't needed for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems done to me. Without all the code it is difficult to see if there is any problem. I have done an example using your own code [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/WqmRzg)

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#databinding",
 data: function() {
  return {
   status: 'all',
   todos: [
    {
     id: 1,
     isDone: false
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     isDone: true
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     isDone: true
    },
    {
     id: 4,
     isDone: false
    },
    {
     id: 5,
     isDone: false
    }
   ],
  };
 },
 methods: {
  changeView: function (newStatus) {
   this.status = newStatus
  }
 },
 computed:{
  activeTodos: function() {
   return this.todos.filter(t => !t.isDone);
  },
  completedTodos: function () {
   return this.todos.filter(t => t.isDone);
  },
  filteredTodos() {
   switch (this.status) {
    case 'active':
     return this.activeTodos;
    case 'completed':
     return this.completedTodos;
    default:
     return this.todos;
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="databinding">
 <p>{{status}} Todos</p>
 <ul id="todos">
  <li v-for="todo in filteredTodos" :key="todo.id">
   {{todo.id}} - {{todo.isDone}}
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="filters">
  <button @click="changeView('all')">All</button>
  <button @click="changeView('active')">Active</button>
  <button @click="changeView('completed')">Completed</button>
 </div>
</div>
```